# IE10 AjaxToolkit Tabpanel error

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, tabpanel, scriptresource.axd

My tabpanel works fine in pretty much all the browsers.
One of my clients complained about IE 10
You basically cannot switch to an other tab like this.
It gives an error, something like:

```
SCRIPT5022: Sys.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Value must be an integer.
Parameter name: x
Actual value was 247.1199951171875. 
ScriptResource.axd, line 5820 character 12
```

The F12 debugger shows me this:
[image]

The Code that you can see in the image is "copyright microsoft", I think it's from ScriptResource.axd

**I did do my reading before asking about this.**

1. This is not helping:
   < meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" >
2. I also found a lot of ideas related to iFrame border width
3. table width change from percent to integer
4. widths remove 'px'
5. iframes - i do have an iframe in the second tab, but i removed it and i still get the error

Comment: Just a shot in the dark..  but have you tried to set the doctype to: <!DOCTYPE html> ?

Comment: @Mike Schwartz - I did, now that you said. It messes up the design, and the tabs are the same. Still cannot switch them :(

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade your project to a newer .NET framework:

http://codecorner.galanter.net/2013/05/01/solution-for-ie10-error-script5022-sys-argumentoutofrangeexception-value-must-be-an-integer/

Comment: I added the custom javascript function to the bottom of the page and that fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure WHY this happens but can propose workaround for this issue. You can download AjaxControlToolkit sources and tweak a bit `$type.getLocation` function in [DomElement.js file](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/a2a6dc6854e0cfb4d11ffa81ad2c2383dfe35086#Client/MicrosoftAjax/Extensions/Sys/UI/DomElement.js)

Add code below before returning new Point object from function:

```
if (typeof offsetX === "number") {
    offset = Math.round(offsetX);
}

if (typeof offsetY === "number") {
    offsetY = Math.round(offsetY);
}
```

After that, rebuild solution and use custom ajaxtoolkit dlls in your project.

Answer (score 0):

This could be your problem:

Asp.net postbacks not working in IE10.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh869299(v=vs.85).aspx
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600100